# Поиск строки в строке

Tags: python, search

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки. Необходима ваша помощь. Есть файл, в котором хранится список параметров.

```
print(params)
['Test 11', 'Test 22', 'Test 33', 'ATest 44']
```

Есть строка, которая после того, как ее распарсят, превращается в словарь.

```
print(d)
{'Test 11':'Success', 'Test 22_434' : 'Success', 'Test 33': 'Fail'}
```

Мне необходимо сравнить каждый из параметров из `params` с ключем из `d`. И если есть совпадение, то записать в  `res`.

Как я это делаю :

```
for param in params:
    if (param in d.keys()):
       res.append(d[param])
    else:
       res.append('')
```

Собственно, проблема в том, что если есть запись в списке `Test 22` и есть ключ в словаре `Test 22_434` то совпадение не происходит, и, соответственно в `res` не происходит запись. 
Как правильно осуществить поиск в данном случае? 
Нашел вот такое решение:

```
length = len(param)
if [item for item in lst if item[:length] == param]:
```

Но как именно передать в `res` значение переменной по ключу, пока не пойму.

Python 3-ей версии.

Comment: Минимальный воспроизводимый пример с "не находит" добавьте. И укажите версию питона, на всякий случай.

Comment: Вероятно, это играет большое значение. Test 22_434 является ключом словаря, который сравниваю со списком...
ищу следующим образом:
`if "Test 22" in d.keys():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")`

где d.keys() хранит в себе строку, вида "Test 22_434"

Comment: Не совсем=) если подскажете, почему поиск не происходит, буду премного благодарен. Только начинаю постигать азы программирования.

Comment: d.keys() - это не строка, а список строк. В списке так просто не получится искать по части строки.

Comment: @stackflow Отредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
params = ['Test 11', 'Test 22', 'Test 33', 'ATest 44']

d = {'Test 11': 'Success', 'Test 22_434': 'Success', 'Test 33': 'Fail'}

res = {}

for param in params:
    for index, value in d.items():
        if param in index:
            res[param] = value

print(res)  # {'Test 11': 'Success', 'Test 22': 'Success', 'Test 33': 'Fail'}
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял задачу: вам нужно вхождение подстроки в строке смотреть на не точное совпадение ключа.

Comment: ДА, то что нужно! Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: @AndyR, пожалуйста!